# No wired and no wireless connexion after installing Ubuntu 14.04.5

Tags: 14.04, networking, internet

I've installed Ubuntu 14.04.5, and the installation was a success.
I restarted and logged in, and then, I tried to have some internet. 
I was looking for WiFi.

But here comes my problem:
I noticed that there wasn't a Wi-Fi connection, so I tried a wired one. But it tries to connect and says that I'm disconnected.

I've read a lot of same problems, but nothing worked till now.

I tried to edit `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and put `managed=true`, but that didn't work...

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Please start here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180#425180 Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.